# OpenGL glGetIntegerv GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL and faced this problem:

Source Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>

int nrAttributes;

int main()
{
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &nrAttributes);

    std::cout << "max vertex: " << nrAttributes << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compile my code with this command:

```
g++ main.cpp --std=c++11 -o main.o src/glad.c -I include -lglfw -lGL -lX11 -lpthread -lXrandr -lXi -ldl
```

I'm on linux mint 18.04 x64

GL info: `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`

```
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.0-38-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 17.2.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

When I run the code I get the following output:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: You need a valid and current [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) to call any OpenGL instruction. See also [OpenGL Loading Library](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) and [Creating an OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL))

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh yes, you're right. Thank you for pointing out. Stupid mistake sorry :| Configured the context and it works. :)

Comment: Should I delete the question from stack? cause it's my stupid mistake

Comment: Of course not. Your mistake will be make again and again through ages! It'll be helpful for everyone (especially with the answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Rabbid76 pointed I needed a valid context to call opengl functions.

Here is the working code, hope it'll help other people.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress);

    int nrAttributes;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &nrAttributes);
    std::cout << "Maximum nr of vertex attributes supported: " << nrAttributes << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```